# How to send a pdf to printing on button click in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to implement the print operation for my Angular 6 application. A pdf will be fetched from service and then on button click, I need to send it to printing. There will be no preview of the PDF. So, I can't use the print option of PDF. Can anyone help me in this regard?

I've tried print.js and jsPdf. jsPdf requires to download the pdf and then open it to print. But I need to do it by a button click. Print.js throws this error-
(I'm using Chrome)

```
ERROR DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at performPrint (http://localhost:4200/modules-deposit-dashboard-deposit-dashboard-module.js:1025:33)
at finishPrint (http://localhost:4200/modules-deposit-dashboard-deposit-dashboard-module.js:1061:5)
at HTMLIFrameElement.printFrame.onload [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYload] (http://localhost:4200/modules-deposit-dashboard-deposit-dashboard-module.js:980:11)
at HTMLIFrameElement.wrapFn (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12361:39)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11594:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42637:33)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11593:36)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11361:47)
at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11669:34)
at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12713:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

For printing, you need to load the file into a separate window within a frame then only you can send it to the printer for printing.

Comment: Or if you have could printer then you can send that file directly from the server to cloud printer via its endpoints.

Comment: So, what should I need to do? Load a pdf in an iframe and then how will I print that iframe?

Comment: Thank you. I've got two option.
1. By implementing a hidden iframe [encodedna](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/how-to-print-a-pdf-document-using-javascript.htm)
2. Print.js [printJs](http://printjs.crabbly.com/)

And the error was showing due to CORS issue. I've added a CORS plugin in chrome and it worked.